# Eloquent query with GroupBy, Sum and Paginator

Tags: laravel

Hi I am trying to do this query

```
$collections = Collection::groupBy(['branch_office_id', DB::raw('MONTH(`created_at`)')])->sum('gross_amount')->paginate(10);
```

But it displays this error:

```
Call to a member function paginate() on string
```

So I wonder how can I do thta without to lose the paginate function ? Thanks.

Comment: The result of sum function is a string, not a collection. Please describe what do you want from the query and tell us about the table you're querying

Comment: I need to sum an amount with the group by, but  it'll be more than 10 rows and for this reason I want to paginate @BABAKASHRAFI

Comment: Do you need to sum on each group of the result?

Comment: @BABAKASHRAFI yes I need that

Answer (score 0):

You can sum on each group of the result by mapping the result of the groupBy and do your summation in the map function. In below code, I suppose you have an array in the map and tried to get the summation of the key.

```
$collections = Collection::groupBy(['branch_office_id', DB::raw('MONTH(`created_at`)')])
    ->map(function($item){
        return array_sum(array_filter($item,function($k=>$v){
           return $k=='gross_amount' ? $v : null;
        }));
    })
    ->paginate(10);
```

Comment: It displays this: message: "syntax error, unexpected '=>' (T_DOUBLE_ARROW), expecting ')'"